# Problem with Spring MVC. How can I create view from two or more object?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

[spring 3.0.5]
[jboss 5.1]

A have a two class

```
public class User {
 private String name;
 private String surname;
 private Address address;
...
sets and gets 
setters and getters  
}

public class Address {
 private String street;

...
setters and getters  
}
```

In Controller I have this code:

```
@Controller 
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/index")
public ModelAndView showForm() {
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("index");
User user = new User();
Address adr = new Address();
mav.addObject("user", user);
mav.addObject("adr", adr);
}
```

And now I want to create from with two input element in JSP

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%> <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

    <html><head><body>
    <form:form method="POST" commandName="user">
    <form:label path="name" />
    <form:input path="name" />
    <form:label path="adr.street" />
    <form:input path="adr.street" />
    </form:form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I runing a got a exception like this one:

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'adr' of bean class [form.User]: Bean property 'adr' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707)
    org.springframework.be

Can someone please explain to me why and how to improve the code?

Comment: Are you sure you don't get compilation error? You haven't returned `ModelAndView` object in showForm method.

Comment: We need to see the actual getters and setters, not just "setters and getters".

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answers you like, e.g. the answer for your previous question by Bozho. It is to encoruage people to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your objects in a wrapper form class and pass it in the model.

```
public class MyForm
{
   public user;
   public address;
   // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Then

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(); // ModelAndView
mav.addObject("myForm", new MyForm()); // e.g.
```

In your model, should address be attached to a user? In other words, it seems to me like a `User` has a one to many relationship to `Address`, and you should let your data access layer handle these concerns.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
   @Id @Column(name="user_id")
   public Long id;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") // so the address table would have a user_id foreign key
   public Address address;
}
```

Comment: What how can I use your response if the relationship between User and Address is 1:N?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119973/form-creation-in-spring-mvc-issue please solve this problem too

Answer (score 2):

You could also do the following, which would prevent you from introducing a new class strictly for display purposes. Spring forms can handle nested properties.

```
User user = new User();
Address adr = new Address();
user.setAddress(adr);
mav.addObject("user", user);
```

In your .jsp you'd reach the address object this way:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user">
<form:label path="name" />
<form:input path="name" />
<form:label path="address.street" />
<form:input path="address.street" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: I recommend testing output of variables with `<c:out value="${user}"></c:out>`. It helped me big time!

Answer (score 0):

The property of the object user is address (I suppose you have a getter called getAddress()), so in the form you have to use address instead of adr:

```
<form:label path="address.street" />
<form:input path="address.street" />
```

or create a getter called getAdr() (as you want)