# Pass and get attributes from one form but more than one entity for

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

Most of the article's talk about how to work with the forms like `<form:form>` Spring tags just with one bean(entity), but in my web app I have more then one bean(actually 3 of them, wich is mirror to my data model in DB(MySql)). What I want is to put values for all of the properties in my entities classes **from one form**(it may be a jsp or xhtml or html, whatever). 
So, I'm kinda new in Spring MVC and as far as I know  it has backing object which comes with `<commandName>` tag in `<form:form>` tag and I suppose to think that it may be just one commandName backing object for each form??

Q:  - Could you please tell me how to easily(or direct me to any example's) to fulfil my pleasant headache.
Q: - It also may have something  to get attributes in one controller class but by different methods. Do I have to store them in session or request? I'm thinking to have ModelAndView class for store multiple attributes in map and after store them in  ModelAndView (in model). What you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope you are having a wonderful day!

I'd suggest you investigate the technique detailed here:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58993-Need-to-Populate-Form-data-into-multiple-java-beans

Also, I'm wondering if there could be a terminology issue here. Do you mean you actually want to have just one form on your UI, with a lot of inputs, or do you really mean you want it all on one SCREEN or page? I say that as its also possible to have multiple forms on one UI screen and go that route... which in fact might be easier, as you could then break up your processing into multiple controllers.

Another consideration on the above relates to screen design... if you are going to be populating the data for several beans from one screen, potentially that could be a LOT of data and your screen could get very cluttered and hard to read. So from that standpoint it might also be better to consider breaking your input controls up into multiple (related) screens. There is a little more about that at the bottom of the article I linked above.

Comment: Hey wSchmidt.. Nice to hear from you. Yeah you know It's seem like really interesting to have one UI(one page) for multiple processing. It's approach looks so complicated-interesting to me. I thought about having one form with alot's of field related to different entities. Thank you for give me url-example.

Comment: Vadim,If the ideas of processing multiple form fields interests you, you might want to check this tutorial technique out also...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986410/1882833

One approach would be to have a seperate class which encapsules the required objects. And then use it as a command to set and get the data.