# form creation in spring mvc issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've two classes

```
public class User {
    private int id;     
    priavte List<Hobby> hobbies;
    //setter getter
}

public class Hobby {
    private int id;
    private String hobbyName;
    //setter getter
}
```

now i want to create form for User.java

my **form.jsp** is

```
<form:form method="POST" action="saveEmployee.html" commandName="user" name="register-form" id="register-form" cssClass="smart-green">

<form:select path="hobbies" multiple="true" size="3">
     <form:option value="1">Cricket</form:option>
     <form:option value="2">Computer Games</form:option>
     <form:option value="3">Tennis</form:option>
     <form:option value="4">Music</form:option>
</form:select>
</form:form>
```

**myController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmployee.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(
            @ModelAttribute("user") User user BindingResult result) {           
        System.out.println(user.getChoice()); // giving null    
    //   usrDao.saveUser(user);
return new ModelAndView("redirect:add.html", model);
}
```

How could i get the value for **List from my form** so that i could get the value?

Comment: rename @ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") to @ModelAttribute("user")  then try it

Comment: i want to ask how i will get the List<Hobby> from there.. i am getting List<String> hobbies;  but i want to get it as List<Hobby> ;

Comment: For starters `2-Games` isn't a valid int, so even if conversion would work would give an exception. HTTP knowns only Strings nothing more nothing less, anything else needs to be converted. Create a `Converter` or `PropertyEditor` which knowns how to convert from a `String` to a `Hobby`. See the [spring reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-typeconversion)

Comment: @ashish :: itrate your list using for loop and add each single hobby in List by creating object of arrayList

Comment: @NiravPrajapati ok... so how would i map this value in my form ??

Comment: take ModelMap and put List of hobbies into it and get it on the jsp page

Comment: @NiravPrajapati can you please desing a form example for me ? m not able to get it yet

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to Bind your multi select value to the POJO Object list is done under  [CustomCollectionEditor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomCollectionEditor.html) class. This is important when binding complex data types such as in your case.

Add this below code in your controller class **myController.java**  :

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)   
{
   binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "hobbies", new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class)
    {
       @Override
       protected Object convertElement(Object element)
        {
           Long id = null;
           String name = null;
           if(element instanceof String && !((String)element).equals(""))  
           {
              //From the JSP 'element' will be a String
              try{
                   id = Long.parseLong((String) element);
                 }
              catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
           else if(element instanceof Long) 
           {
              //From the database 'element' will be a Long
              id = (Long) element;
           }
           // Here you can get Hobby object from database based on the id you have got.
           //You any other way you can get hobbyName and set in hobby object and return it
           Hobby h = new Hobby();
           h.setId(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));
           h.setHobbyName(name);
           return h;
     }
  });  
}
```

Reference Link for more details :
[SpringMVC bind Multi Select with object in Form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746371/springmvc-custom-collection-editor-not-returning-data-to-jsp)
[Multiple Select in Spring 3.0 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331532/multiple-select-in-spring-3-0-mvc).